# How to create a encrypted zip file can be decompressed by winzip/7zip

Tags: c#, encryption, zip, aes

I've used AESManaged Class to encrypt a zip file, but it couldn't be decompressed by winzip/7zip. I can only decompress it after decrypting in my code.

Below is the code I used to encrypt and decrypt. Anyone can help?

```
private static void EncryptFile(string input, string output, string pwd)
    {
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            FileStream fsCrypt=null;
            try
            {
                byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);

                fsCrypt = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create);

                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            int data;

                            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                            {
                                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                            }
                            aes.Clear();
                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                aes.Clear();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(fsCrypt!=null)
                {
                    fsCrypt.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static void DecryptFile(string input, string output, string pwd)
    {
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            FileStream fsCrypt = null;
            try
            {
                byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);

                fsCrypt = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open);
                {

                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            int data;

                            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                            {
                                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
                            }
                            aes.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                aes.Clear();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fsCrypt != null)
                {
                    fsCrypt.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did I understand this correctly that you first create your ZIP file and THEN encrypt it? Of course no unpacker application can read it - it IS encrypted... :-)

Comment: Send your code to Winzip guys and tell them to create a new winzip app so that it uses your code to decrypt then unzip it as well. Because my friend there is no other way to do it. Think on your question before you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the internal structure of a zip file with your encryption algorithm.
How could you expect that an external zip manager recognizes your encrypted file as a valid zip file?
If you really want to use a password protected zip file then use a library that can do this for you without destroying the zip file structure.

I recommend this library [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to unzip a file if the format is not that of zip. Once you encrypt a file you the format is no longer zip.

But it is possible to perform both encryption and compression in C#. For better compression ratio you would need to compress the file first and then encrypt.

You can use [GZipstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to compress and the code you have depicted to encrypt.

Comment: If I use GZipStream to compress first and then use the code I posted to encrypt, need I input password when I use 7zip to decompress the file?

Comment: This answer is not complete. WinZip does not encrypt the archive, it encrypts each file, with an option to encrypt the filename. I would just use a library that supports doing exactly that.

Comment: @Ramhound I never said Winzip encrypts the archive. I just pointed out the fact the it is possible to do compression in code using GZipstream